# Android Java - Message at a random range of time, every second check

Tags: java, android

For a side project of mine, I'm devoloping an android app with java. I don't know java a lot but i'm trying ^^.

The project is to have an Alarm at a random time in a certain range. The problem is that my chronometer and button freeze, but everything still works! Does anyone has maybe another solution for the thread.sleep ??

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    }
    public void StartChrono(View view) {
         final Chronometer chrono = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
         chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
         chrono.start();
         //Tick();
     }
     public int RandomTime(int min, int max)
     {
         int random = max - min;
         Random rand= new Random();
         random = rand.nextInt(random)+min;
         return random;
     }
     public boolean CheckUp(int randomtime,int chronotime)
     {
        boolean check = false;

        if(randomtime== chronotime)
         {
             check = true;
         }

        return check;
     }
     public void Tick()
     {
        boolean check = false;
        int randomtime = RandomTime(20,150);
        int time=1;

        do
         {  
            check = CheckUp(randomtime,time);
            time = time +1;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                AlertDialog alertDialog;
                alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error - 000");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Could not check!");
                alertDialog.show();
            }

         }while(check == false);

        if(check == true)
        {
            AlertDialog alertDialog;
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Yuy");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Switch!");
            alertDialog.show();
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use Thread.sleep(), I would use a Timer.

You can set a time and the Timer automatically calls the associated task.

In Android it would work something like this:

http://android.okhelp.cz/timer-simple-timertask-java-android-example/

I used it once myself, but that is some time ago.

Btw.:

You don't have to write a method to check for a boolean value.

This also works:

```
boolean  check = 5>3;
System.out.println("check: " + check);//"check true"
```

Comment: Aaah big thanks, I was looking for a timer. But couldn't understand the documentations on the other websites! Thanx this is solved !

Comment: no problem. but please don't forget to vote my answer up and check it as the right answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd definately use a Handler for this task: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

A basic example would be this:

```
long timeDelay = 1000; // Set this to your random number.
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     // Do whatever you need to do after a specified interval.  
    }
}, timeDelay);
```

Instantiate the Handler inside your onCreate and keep the reference around so you can call it inside your method.

Just to clarify, why you can't use Thread.sleep() for "sleeping" a specific amount of time, is this: when you call Thread.sleep() you call it on the UI thread, so every component running on the UI thread (buttons, textfields and so on) will "sleep" for the given amount of time and hence you basically halt the whole application.

Also see the documentation for Thread.sleep:

> Causes the thread which sent this message to sleep for the given
>   interval of time (given in milliseconds).